# Generic methods to read/write to file all classes that extend X

Tags: java, repository, filereader, opencsv

sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I'm getting kind of desperate to solve a problem for a school project (due date tomorrow).
I'm very new to Java and this project involves storing data from certain objects to a local repository and also reading the data from the repo.
The repository handler class is in one package and the objects are in another.

My problem is that I don't know how to make generic methods in the handler to be able to read and write any object that extends X.

For example, let's say I have Fruit.

Apple extends Fruit.
Orange extends Fruit.

Both have their own unique attributes that I need to write/read to/from a file.

I wanted to have a method like
ArrayList repo_reader(String filepath)
That reads from a file and returns Apples and Oranges.

The only way that I know how to do this is having a field in the file stating which type of fruit it is, reading it and throwing it to a switch case like

switch (fruit_type){
case "Orange":
Orange orange = new Orange();  orange.setOrangeSpecificAttribute("ble");
FruitBasket.add(orange);
case "Apple":
Apple apple = new Apple();        apple.setAppleSpecificAttribute("bla");
FruitBasket.add(apple);

But then the method wouldn't be generic. Everytime that someone creates a new Fruit class, they would have to also change the repo_handler methods accordingly. The same would also happen with the writing method.

I could have the Fruit classes all implement their own method to write and read, but I don't want that. I want repo_handler class to deal with all the file reading and writing.

Again, sorry if it's a stupid question, and thanks for your guys' attention!

Btw, it's a CSV file, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have different readers/factories dependending on the contents of some String. That is, the String acts as identifier for the reader/factory to use.

You can use a map to map identifiers (keys) to readers/factories (values). As the latter must be registered, I'd use the service loader mechanism as described in [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), and iterate over all services to register them in this map.

Having this, you can look up the needed reader/factory in the map and use it to read/create new Fruit instances.

Step #1: Service Provider Interface

```
package com.mycompany.fruit;

public interface FruitFactory {
    String getIdentifier();
    Fruit createFruit(String[] attributes); // change params to your needs
}
```

Step #2: Service implementation

```
package com.mycompany.fruit;

public class AppleFactory implements FruitFactory {
    public String getIdentifier() { return "Apple"; }
    public Fruit createFruit(String[] attributes) {
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        apple.setCommonAttribute(attributes[1]);
        apple.setSpecificAttribute(attributes[2]);
        // ...
        return apple;
    }
}
```

Step #3: Register factories

Put a file `com.mycompany.fruit.FruitFactory` in `META-INF/services`. Put the fully qualified class name of each implementation of FruitFactory on separate lines in this file. For example:

```
com.mycompany.fruit.AppleFactory
com.mycompany.fruit.OrangeFactory
...
```

Step #4: Load the services and use them

```
public class MyFruitReader {
    Map<String, FruitFactory> factories;

    public MyFruitReader(...) {
        ServiceLoader<FruitFactory> loader = new ServiceLoader(FruitFactory.class);
        for (FruitFactory factory : loader) {
            factories.put(factory.getIdentifier(), factory);
        }

    // usage 
    private Fruit getFruit(String[] row) {
        String fruitType = row[0];
        FruitFactory factory = factories.get(fruitType);
        if (factory == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return factory.createFruit(row);
    }

    // read the CSV file and call getFruit()
    // ...
```

Keep in mind, that this are just sketches to provide a rough overview of this topic. You'll have to adapt it to your needs, add exception handling, fix errors, and so on.